# pmin(x, 60) and subset regression

Tags: r, regression, splines, regression-strategies

Is there any difference between

```
y ~ pmin(x, 60) + sex , df = data
```

and

```
y ~ x + sex, df = subset(data, x <=60)
```

If they are the same, then why use `pmin(x, 60)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pmin` will replace all instances of `x` greater than 60 by 60, and leave the vector `x` of the same length as it was before applying `pmin`. On the other hand, `subset` will filter the data, so it will reduce the sample size to those units satisfying the subsetting condition. Hence, the two datasets are, in general, different.

Here is a simple example.

```
set.seed(25)

# generate some data
dd <- data.frame(x = c(1,3,60, 5, 100, 7, 200), 
                 sex = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F"),
                 y = runif(7))

# "pmined" data
dd2 <- dd
dd2$x <- pmin(dd$x, 60)

# filtered data
> subset(dd, x<= 60)
   x sex         y
1  1   M 0.4161184
2  3   F 0.6947637
3 60   M 0.1488006
4  5   F 0.8973850
6  7   M 0.9851157


# "pminded" data
> dd2

  x sex         y
1  1   M 0.4161184
2  3   F 0.6947637
3 60   M 0.1488006
4  5   F 0.8973850
5 60   F 0.1243921
6  7   M 0.9851157
7 60   F 0.6260962
```

Comment: Thanks your point is noted. Also just a headsup, I poseted another related question here, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603083/breaking-the-regression-line-into-two-pieces