# Breaking the regression line into two pieces

Tags: regression, splines, regression-strategies

My X & Y variables are associated like this below and I am trying to fit a simple linear regression model `(y ~ x , data= df)` , to estimate `β1` .

[image]

However I am not confident about extending the linear slope to values beyond 30. I want to restrict the regression slope to only x < 30

For x > 30 I want to slope to be horizontal so that β1 = 0. In other words breaking my linear regression line into two pieces x < 30 and x>30.

[image]

How can i do that ?

Comment: This would be a "linear plateau model".

Comment: I think a potential problem with this approach is that you are choosing the *x*-value where the segments meet *apriori*.  Usually when linear plateau models are implemented, this *critical-x* value is determined from the data, and could could also get a confidence interval for this *critical-x*.  Often for these models, it's the value of the *critical-x* that is really of interest.  It answers the question, *Above what value of x is y not likely to increase with increasing x?*

Comment: @SalMangiafico, Thanks Sal, I see you also provided an example for this in your website. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the regression into two parts:
$$y_i = \beta_0^{<30} + \beta_1^{<30} x_i + e_i, \space x < 30 \\
y_i = \beta_0^{\ge30} + e_i, \space x_i \ge 30$$
We can write this as a single equation:
$$
y_i = I(x_i < 30)(\beta_0^{<30} + \beta_1^{<30} x_i) + I(x_i\ge30)(\beta_0^{\ge30}) + e_i
$$
where $I(.)$ is an indicator variable, equal to $1$ if the condition is met and $0$ otherwise, so it acts like a switch, turning on the left side or right side of the model.

We know that $\beta_0^{\ge30}$ needs to be constrained to be whatever value is at the end of the sloped line, i.e., the predicted value of $y$ when $x = 30$ based on the model for the left half. So we can rewrite $\beta_0^{\ge30}$ as $(\beta_0^{<30} + \beta_1^{<30}30)$ and then substitute, so we get
$$
y_i = I(x_i < 30)(\beta_0^{<30} + \beta_1^{<30} x_i) + I(x_i\ge30)(\beta_0^{<30} + \beta_1^{<30}30) + e_i
$$
This is a regression model with two coefficients to be estimated, so we can rearrange the terms to get a model in the form $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^*_i + e_i$. First, we'll simplify notation by setting $d_i = I(x_i < 30)$ so that $1 - d_i = I(x_i \ge 30)$. Also, also I'll write $\beta_k^{<30}$ as $\beta_k$:
\begin{align}
y_i &= d_i(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i) + (1-d_i)(\beta_0 + \beta_1 30) + e_i \\
    &= \beta_0 d_i + \beta_1 x_i d_i + \beta_0(1-d_i) + \beta_1 30(1-d_i) + e_i \\
&= \beta_0 (d_i + (1-d_i))+ \beta_1 (x_i d_i + 30(1-d_i)) + e_i \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 (x_i d_i + 30(1-d_i)) + e_i \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^*_i + e_i
\end{align}
where $x^*_i = x_i d_i + 30(1-d_i)$.

So now we can simply create a new predictor, $x^*$, and fit the regression model. Here's an example of how to do that in R:

```r
set.seed(100)
n <- 50
x <- sort(runif(n, 0, 40))
y <- 6 + 2 * x + rnorm(n, 0, 30)

d <- 1 * (x < 30)
x_star <- x * d + 30*(1-d)

fit <- lm(y ~ x_star)
y_hat <- fitted(fit)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, y_hat, col = "red")
```

[image]

```r
# This lets you generate predictions for any value of x
fit <- lm(y ~ I(x * (x < 30) + 30 * (x >= 30)))

y_hat <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = 0:60))
plot(x, y, xlim = c(0, 60))
lines(0:60, y_hat, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks I will think about this.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily extend the solution by @Noah to a non-fixed break point, which you want to estimate from the data. There is the problem, however, that the fitted function $f$ is not differentiable in the break point $x_0$. It is
$$f(x,b_0,b_1,x_0)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
b_0 + b_1 x & \mbox{ for } x\leq x_0 \\
b_0+b_1 x_0 & \mbox{ for } x> x_0
\end{array}\right.$$

or, implemented in R

```
f <- function(x, b0, b1, x0) {
  ifelse(x < x0, b0 + b1*x, b0 + b1*x0)
}
```

This means that the R function for general least squares optimization `nls` might report a "singular gradient" error, e.g. for the following example:

```
set.seed(100)
n <- 50
x <- runif(n, 0, 40)
y <- f(x, 6, 2, 30) + rnorm(n, 0, 30)

fit <- nls(y ~ f(x, b0, b1, x0), start=list(b0=0, b1=1, x0=10))
```

This can be easily circumvented by using a more robust minimization algorithm that also works for non-differentiable functions, e.g. Nelder-Mead, which is the default algorithm in the R function `optim`:

```
# helper function defining the LSQ objective function
ssq <- function(par, x, y) {
  sum((y - f(x, par[1], par[2], par[3]))^2)
}

res <- optim(par=c(0,1,10), ssq, x=x, y=y)
if (res$convergence != 0) {
  stop("optim not converged")
}

# visualize result
# fitted parameters are stored in res$par
plot(x,y)
xr <- range(x)
xx <- seq(xr[1], xr[2], by=0.1)
lines(xx, f(xx, res$par[1], res$par[2], res$par[3]), col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: thank in Epidemiology the scientists want to chose the point where they think there is a break, so for now my use case has a pre specified breakpoint but I will use this approach as a sensitivity analysis.

Comment: @Science11 Do yoou have a real world data set as an example? This looks like an interesting example for a class exercise.

Comment: the exact use case is proprietary, if the paper is published I will come back here and provide the link to the url with the dataset. For now , if I may, I would recommend, age vs income datataset in Introduction to Statistical Learning by Tibsharani et all, pg 272. Very few datapoints after 60years and if we use a linear regression the slope may mislead people into thinking that salary increases after age 60 when in reality it may decrease or we have very few data points to estimate this accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of the income dataset, which seems to be even vailable in the R package *arules*: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/arules/html/Income.html. I am looking forward to your dataset when you have finished your project. And please also provide a link to the publication so that I can learn more about your use case and cite it if I use this dataset somewhere.