# Determine what is the break point for the slope change in R

Tags: r, change-point

I am trying to create a plot with 2 linear regression lines for each group (i.e., `CAD`, and `Healthy`). One linear regression line before the `break point` and one after it, for each group.

I would like to determine from which `power` value, the slope starts to be under `3.9` in each group.

At the moment, I can only create a plot with linear regression in each group with this code:

```
df_sum %>%
  mutate(absVO2 = absVO2*1000) %>% 
  filter(percent_power < 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = power, y = absVO2, color = group)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 30, label.y = c(2000,3000), 
                        formula = y ~ x,
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~"))) +
  xlab("VE (L/min)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("VC", O[2]," (L/min)"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(25, 100), breaks = seq(25, 100, by = 25)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill ="white", colour = "white"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_blank()
  )
```

Here are my data.

```
structure(list(power = c(25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 
25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 
85L, 100L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L, 
175L, 190L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 20L, 30L, 
40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 25L, 40L, 
55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 25L, 40L, 55L, 70L, 85L, 25L, 40L, 
55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L, 175L, 25L, 40L, 
55L, 70L, 85L, 100L, 115L, 130L, 145L, 160L, 175L, 190L, 205L, 
20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 
100L, 110L, 120L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L), absVO2 = c(0.739, 
0.81975, 0.95125, 1.07525, 1.199, 1.34575, 1.49775, 0.66125, 
0.7485, 0.855, 0.9845, 1.1495, 1.3465, 1.451, 1.5985, 0.61675, 
0.717, 0.86275, 0.98575, 1.13, 1.262, 0.8835, 0.94575, 1.08125, 
1.244, 1.30475, 1.4735, 1.679, 1.79075, 1.96, 2.0405, 2.34425, 
2.4435, 0.5925, 0.661, 0.7435, 0.87875, 0.9435, 0.99675, 1.11425, 
1.20275, 0.9255, 1.02925, 1.11675, 1.19725, 1.24775, 1.42625, 
1.54225, 1.59425, 1.69675, 1.776, 1.94525, 2.0395, 0.535, 0.5845, 
0.76875, 0.982, 1.09975, 1.259, 1.3265, 0.7205, 0.86825, 0.9235, 
1.01075, 1.17275, 0.7435, 0.76575, 0.96075, 1.0975, 1.21975, 
1.34525, 1.50625, 1.6755, 1.86325, 2.0465, 2.1395, 0.613, 0.85525, 
0.98, 1.076, 1.287, 1.4615, 1.59325, 1.6965, 1.884, 1.998, 2.1425, 
2.31275, 2.474, 0.81075, 0.8035, 0.8645, 1.076, 1.119, 1.255, 
1.33825, 1.499, 0.8105, 0.8865, 1.03725, 1.134, 1.26675, 1.36275, 
1.4455, 1.52875, 0.64675, 0.6645, 0.742, 0.81675, 0.983, 1.06875, 
1.155), percent_power = c(21.7391304347826, 34.7826086956522, 
47.8260869565217, 60.8695652173913, 73.9130434782609, 86.9565217391304, 
100, 19.2307692307692, 30.7692307692308, 42.3076923076923, 53.8461538461538, 
65.3846153846154, 76.9230769230769, 88.4615384615385, 100, 25, 
40, 55, 70, 85, 100, 13.1578947368421, 21.0526315789474, 28.9473684210526, 
36.8421052631579, 44.7368421052632, 52.6315789473684, 60.5263157894737, 
68.4210526315789, 76.3157894736842, 84.2105263157895, 92.1052631578947, 
100, 22.2222222222222, 33.3333333333333, 44.4444444444444, 55.5555555555556, 
66.6666666666667, 77.7777777777778, 88.8888888888889, 100, 15.3846153846154, 
23.0769230769231, 30.7692307692308, 38.4615384615385, 46.1538461538462, 
53.8461538461538, 61.5384615384615, 69.2307692307692, 76.9230769230769, 
84.6153846153846, 92.3076923076923, 100, 21.7391304347826, 34.7826086956522, 
47.8260869565217, 60.8695652173913, 73.9130434782609, 86.9565217391304, 
100, 29.4117647058824, 47.0588235294118, 64.7058823529412, 82.3529411764706, 
100, 14.2857142857143, 22.8571428571429, 31.4285714285714, 40, 
48.5714285714286, 57.1428571428571, 65.7142857142857, 74.2857142857143, 
82.8571428571429, 91.4285714285714, 100, 12.1951219512195, 19.5121951219512, 
26.8292682926829, 34.1463414634146, 41.4634146341463, 48.780487804878, 
56.0975609756098, 63.4146341463415, 70.7317073170732, 78.0487804878049, 
85.3658536585366, 92.6829268292683, 100, 22.2222222222222, 33.3333333333333, 
44.4444444444444, 55.5555555555556, 66.6666666666667, 77.7777777777778, 
88.8888888888889, 100, 41.6666666666667, 50, 58.3333333333333, 
66.6666666666667, 75, 83.3333333333333, 91.6666666666667, 100, 
25, 37.5, 50, 62.5, 75, 87.5, 100), group = c("CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -112L))
```

EDIT:
I am trying to explain: For each group, I would like to write down a `percentage_power` (break point) that will provide two slopes: one for the regression line before the break point, one after. Same for the other group. Then, I would like to compare "statistically" these two break points (47% vs 62% in the example), and also compare (providing a p-value) the slopes before the break point between the two groups (8.7 vs 9.3), and then the slopes after the break point between the two groups (3.1 vs 3.3). I hope it makes sens. Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: What do you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited my question. I can only generate a plot with regression line in each group.

Comment: Please make this a minimal reproducible example by including library statements and removing code not related to problem.

Comment: I don't think it is a statistical question but mostly about a code to generate slope and find the break point.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have 2 groups, and moreover it is based on a break point that is already known in the context, while my question is to determine this break point in my context. Thank you!

Comment: May be worth looking at the [strucchange](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=strucchange) package

Comment: It might be possible, but again, I don't know how to run that with my 2 groups here.

Comment: "One linear regression line before the break point and one after it, for each group." So, you want [segmented regression models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html)? I strongly recommend to not conflate fitting models and plotting predictions. Consider these independent challenges.

Comment: Thank you Roland. I am really naive to that, but can I use it with ggplot2? I am not able to generate it...

Comment: Yes, you can. But, as I said, I don't recommend that. Fit the model outside ggplot2. Do model diagnostics and stuff. Then plot predictions with ggplot2.

Comment: I don't think I am good enough to run that unfortunately. I'm still new in R. But thank you for your advice!

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to fit *two* lines over the entire range, one for each *group*? This can be done with `lm(absVO2 ~ group*power, yourdata)`. Or do you want to ignore the group label and want to fit different lines for two different ranges of *power* with all data points, possible with (or without) the constraint of continuity? This would require to use a numeric optimization (R function `optim`) if the break point is unknown. Maybe you can draw manually what your expected result is.

Comment: Ok. I have updated the question and added an expected figure. I am trying to explain: For each group, I would like to write down a `percentage_power` (break point) that will provide two slopes: one for the regression line before the break point, one after. Same for the other group. Then, I would like to compare "statistically" these two break points, and also compare (providing a p-value) the slopes before the break point between the two groups, and then the slopes after the break point between the two groups. I hope it makes sens. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please explain why the following two answers do not solve your problem:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7529/244807 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603256/244807. Concerning your question about significance: The simplest apporach would be to fit a linear model `absVO2 ~ group*power` only on the data to the right of the rightmost breakpoint and then check which an ANOVA whether the predictor `group:power` is significant.